# AB test, but, more like ABCDEFGH

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

When doing an AB test (for website variations), I understand you should check the significance before drawing conclusions with any of the tools you can find googling "ab test calculator", now how would you do that with more than 2 variables?

Let's say I have this data :

```
Variation   Impressions   Clicks
A           400           20
B           300           10
C           100           2
```

What conclusion can I draw from that? If I stick with the AB test (which I feel is wrong), I can do :

A vs B : no significant difference

B vs C : no significant difference

So I could conclude that, overall, there is no difference there and no variation is bad enough to stop testing.

But if I do A vs C : significant difference! So now I want to stop C.

OK so what I feel is that there is another way to compare these. What would it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on [Analysis of Variance, also known as ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance). Any introductory applied statistics textbook will explain ANOVA to you.

Here are [some CrossValidated questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ANOVA%20is%3aq) that may be helpful - you may want to sort by votes and skim the first few pages of results.

Of course, you can't apply ANOVA to just one data point per A/B/C group, nor should you draw conclusions from $n=1$ observation each, but I assume you know this.

Comment: Thx for showing me the right direction. 

I'm just a web developer trying to figure out what's the best option for my site, so TBH I was looking for a magic unicorn where I could just put my values and draw conclusions just like those AB significance calculator you can find online.

If you have some more minutes would you care to explain what conclusions you would draw from my fictitious example? If this is not "statistically significant" and you can't draw conclusions you can change the values. Ah if you don't have the time, thanks anyway, the first answer is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Ah there was a limit of characters in the comment so I cut that part but since I can add another comment I'll put it anyway : I started reading the Wikipedia and there's many stuff I don't understand there either, that's why I'm asking you for a little more, but obviously I will spend more time on it and hopefully I'll understand more soon (hopefully before 2018 :)

Comment: OK, some days later : sounds like your last sentence prevent me from drawing conclusions from my dataset so ANOVA not appropriate to my needs. Thanks anyway.